# Elasticsearch: Aggregations request timezone field not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch

The query created by Postman and the request created by QueryBuilder are the same, but the TimeZone field is not applied to java requests.

here is request target mapping info

```
"timeArchived": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||epoch_millis"
            }
```

here is java request source

```
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        sourceBuilder.trackTotalHits(true);
        sourceBuilder.size(0);
        sourceBuilder.query(query);
        RangeQueryBuilder rangeQuery = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("timeArchived").timeZone("Asia/Seoul").gte(sTime).lte(eTime);
        query.filter(rangeQuery);
        query.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("domain", domain));
        
        sourceBuilder.aggregation(AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram("mailDate").field("timeArchived").fixedInterval(DateHistogramInterval.hours(1)).timeZone(ZoneId.of("ROK")));
        
        SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
        request.source(sourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.search(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

here is created request query. java builder request and postman request same query.

```
{
   "size":0,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "domain":{
                     "value":"test.com",
                     "boost":1.0
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":[
            {
               "range":{
                  "timeArchived":{
                     "from":"2020-09-18 04:00:00",
                     "to":"2020-09-18 10:09:46",
                     "include_lower":true,
                     "include_upper":true,
                     "time_zone":"Asia/Seoul",
                     "boost":1.0
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "adjust_pure_negative":true,
         "boost":1.0
      }
   },
   "track_total_hits":2147483647,
   "aggregations":{
      "mailDate":{
         "date_histogram":{
            "field":"timeArchived",
            "time_zone":"ROK",
            "fixed_interval":"1h",
            "offset":21600000,
            "order":{
               "_key":"asc"
            },
            "keyed":false,
            "min_doc_count":0
         }
      }
   }
}
```

but request response not same. java request timeZone option not working.

this postman request result timeZone option working.

```
{
    "took": 484,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 177,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "mailDate": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2020-09-18 04:00:00",
                    "key": 1600369200000,
                    "doc_count": 8
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2020-09-18 05:00:00",
                    "key": 1600372800000,
                    "doc_count": 16
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2020-09-18 06:00:00",
                    "key": 1600376400000,
                    "doc_count": 4
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2020-09-18 07:00:00",
                    "key": 1600380000000,
                    "doc_count": 10
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2020-09-18 08:00:00",
                    "key": 1600383600000,
                    "doc_count": 17
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2020-09-18 09:00:00",
                    "key": 1600387200000,
                    "doc_count": 98
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2020-09-18 10:00:00",
                    "key": 1600390800000,
                    "doc_count": 24
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

but java request timeZone option not working. response is UTC time.

```
{
   "took":918,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":3,
      "successful":3,
      "skipped":0,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":{
         "value":223,
         "relation":"eq"
      },
      "max_score":null,
      "hits":[
         
      ]
   },
   "aggregations":{
      "date_histogram#mailDate":{
         "buckets":[
            {
               "key_as_string":"2020-09-17T19:00:00.000Z",
               "key":1600369200000,
               "doc_count":8
            },
            {
               "key_as_string":"2020-09-17T20:00:00.000Z",
               "key":1600372800000,
               "doc_count":16
            },
            {
               "key_as_string":"2020-09-17T21:00:00.000Z",
               "key":1600376400000,
               "doc_count":4
            },
            {
               "key_as_string":"2020-09-17T22:00:00.000Z",
               "key":1600380000000,
               "doc_count":10
            },
            {
               "key_as_string":"2020-09-17T23:00:00.000Z",
               "key":1600383600000,
               "doc_count":17
            },
            {
               "key_as_string":"2020-09-18T00:00:00.000Z",
               "key":1600387200000,
               "doc_count":98
            },
            {
               "key_as_string":"2020-09-18T01:00:00.000Z",
               "key":1600390800000,
               "doc_count":70
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

How do I set timezone in java?

Answer (score 1):

The query looks good and I tested this out from my end. The possible reason is the incorrect SearchSourceBuilder being passed at line `request.source(mailSourceBuilder);`. I tried the following:

**Code:**

```java
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("my_index");
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram("histogramtest").field("createdOn")
                .fixedInterval(DateHistogramInterval.hours(1)).timeZone(ZoneId.of("ROK")));
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

**Response:**

```
{"buckets":[{"key_as_string":"2020-05-04T16:00:00.000+09:00","key":1588575600000,"doc_count":3},{"key_as_string":"2020-05-04T17:00:00.000+09:00","key":1588579200000,"doc_count":0},{"key_as_string":"2020-05-04T18:00:00.000+09:00","key":1588582800000,"doc_count":0},{"key_as_string":"2020-05-04T19:00:00.000+09:00","key":1588586400000,"doc_count":3},{"key_as_string":"2020-05-04T20:00:00.000+09:00","key":1588590000000,"doc_count":0},{"key_as_string":"2020-05-04T21:00:00.000+09:00","key":1588593600000,"doc_count":3},
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the parameter is just a mistake to modify when uploading the question, and even when passing the correct argument, TIMEZONE points to UTC time.   {"buckets":[{"key_as_string":"2020-09-17T22:00:00.000Z","key":1600380000000,"doc_count":10}   Maybe there are other problems?

Comment: Did you check with the client versions? I am using 7.9.1.

Comment: I using 7.7.0v elasticsearch and rest client also 7.7.0v